# WooCommerce PayPal IPN (checkout fields)

Tags: wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, paypal-ipn

I am working on a self hosted Wordpress website where we sell physical products and memberships and using the WooCommerce standard plugin to handle our cart / checkout. I use a tag to create the checkout page "[woocommerce_checkout]". For payment we only use PayPal. I have figured out how to capture the PayPal IPN so that I can do additional processing (i.e creating the member in the database) and this seems to work with no issue.

The problem is I would like capture the fields on the WooCommerce checkout page to be available in the IPN response from PayPal. For instance, first name, last name, address, email etc. How can I specify that these are included in the PayPal IPN? Is this available in the settings for the plugin or will I need to make my own implementation of the checkout page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out you can get the information from the woo commerce tables in the database. The IPN contains the order id which can be used to look up more information about the order.